# Use definition of limit (not pinching principle) to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {xy(x+y)}{x^2+y^2}=0.$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

My attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Choose $\delta=\cdots$

Suppose $0<\sqrt {x^2+y^2}<\delta$.

$\left|\frac{xy(x+y)}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac{\lvert xy\rvert \lvert x+y\rvert}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{\lvert x+y\rvert}{2}\leq \lvert x+ y \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y\rvert\lt\cdots\lt \epsilon.$

Could someone help complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|x| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the same for $|y|$, then
$$|x| + |y| \leq 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$
So, put $\delta = \varepsilon/2$ and you are done.